# Transactional Replication: Distributor to Subscriber failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, publish-subscribe, transactional-replication

I just set up transactional replication following the instructions [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/transactional-replication-2008-r2/2/)

I am getting the following error:

- The process could not connect to Subscriber 'SUBSCRIBERSERVER'.
  (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)
- Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Source:
  MSSQLServer, Error number: 18456)

I have pinged the subscriber server and it is up. I can log in to it without any issues. I have googled this quiet a bit now and am not sure how to resolve it. Anyone suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The error is straight-forward.  Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.  That login does not have access to the Subscriber.  According to Replication Agent Security Model (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx), the account that is used to connect to the Subscriber must at minimum be a member of the db_owner fixed database role in the subscription database.  This is covered in the section "Distribution Agent for a push subscription".

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I got this resolved. However, my subscriber database is being generated correctly but no data is being replicated. All tables are empty. I even restored the replication database manually and after replication was established, the contents were all removed. Perhaps I should open a new thread for this?

Comment: Is the Log Reader Agent running?  Are there any errors in Replication Monitor?

Comment: @amindomeniko would you mind share how you resolve the issue? I have followed microsoft's tutorial on database transactional replication and ran into the same issue. Thanks.